# Compare two images by using AWS Rekognition error

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-rekognition

I try to compare the two image which is in s3.
So I have completed the code by referring to the following:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/rekognition/latest/dg/faces-comparefaces.html

I made the IdentityPool with Role(S3 Full Access, Rekognition Full Access).

```
try{

            CompareFacesRequest compareFacesRequest = new CompareFacesRequest().
                    withSourceImage(new Image().withS3Object(new S3Object().withName(photo1).withBucket(bucket))).
                    withTargetImage(new Image().withS3Object(new S3Object().withName(photo2).withBucket(bucket))).withSimilarityThreshold(80F);

            CompareFacesResult result = amazonRekognitionClient.compareFaces(compareFacesRequest);
            List<CompareFacesMatch> list = result.getFaceMatches();

            Log.d(TAG,"testing..");

            if (!list.isEmpty()){

                Log.d(TAG,"face match");

                for (CompareFacesMatch match:list){
                    Log.d(TAG,match.getFace() + "" + match.getSimilarity());
                }

            }else{

                Log.d(TAG,"face dismatch");

            }

        }catch (Exception e){

            Log.d(TAG,"Exception occurs");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

But it makes that error.
com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.InvalidS3ObjectException: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions. (Service: AmazonRekognition; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidS3ObjectException; Request ID: 2c4720e3-0e67-11e9-a286-7761b1c828e5)

I thought if I make a mistake of IAM, the app can't upload the file.
I try to upload the file with same credentialsProvider, upload success.

I don't think that's what happened because of permission.

S3 region is in Seoul, and Cognito IdentityPool region is AP_NORTHEAST_2

is there any information to get s3 object with Rekognition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use rekognitionClient.setRegion() operation.

E.g: amazonrekognitionClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));

Hope it might Helps.